# Print out a specific number of permutations (java)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, permutation, swap

The code I have written takes elements of an array and goes through the array to give all permutations. But I need it to only display a certain number of permutations:

The final code is to give only 6 permutations of 9 elements (in other words, print the first 60480 arrangements of the total 362880 outputs). For simplicity, I'm working with 4 elements in the array and I get all 24 arrangements to print out. But I need the code to work for any number of permutations. For example, if I need it to print out 1-permutation, the code should print the first 4 arrangements - ABCD, ABDC, ACBD, and ACDB. I'm unsure how to solve this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    String[] myArray = {"A","B","C", "D"};
    int size = myArray.length; 
    permutation(myArray, 0, size-1);

    // Calculate Permutations
    int n=size;
    int r=6; // subject to change
    int p = n - r;
    int total=1;
    int total2=1;
    int total3=0;

    for (int top=n; top>0; top--)
    {
        total *= top;
    }

    if ((n-r<0))
    {
     System.out.println("r value cannot be greater than array size");
     total3=0;
    }
    else 
    {
        for (int bot=1; bot<=p; bot++)
        {
            if (p==0) // should be -- else if (p==0) -- after correction
            {
                total2=1;
            }
            else
            {
                total2 *= bot;
            }
        }
        total3 = total/total2;
    }

    System.out.printf("%d permutations of %d elements = %d\n",r,n,total3);
    // end calculation

}
// end main

// print array
public static void prtArray(String[] myArray, int size)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%s", myArray[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

// swap elements    
public static void swap(String[] myArray, int i, int j) {
    String temp;
    temp = myArray[i];
    myArray[i]=myArray[j];
    myArray[j]=temp;
}

// permutation 
private static void permutation(String[] myArray, int b, int e)
{
    if (b == e)
        prtArray(myArray, e+1); // accounts for array of size 1
    else
    {
        for(int i = b; i <= e; i++)
        {

            swap(myArray, i, b);
            permutation(myArray, b+1, e);
            swap(myArray, i, b);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Change `System.out.printf("%d", myArray[i]);` to `System.out.printf("%s", myArray[i]);`. `%d` stands for a number, `%s` for string, and you're trying to print strings.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not getting any errors, but the elements are not swapping (It's just printing out 24 lines of ABCD)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution for three out of five elements:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class Permutations {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] myArray = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(myArray);

    List<List<String>> perms = makePerms(list, 3);
    perms.forEach(Permutations::printPerm);
    System.out.println("Size = " + perms.size());
}

  private static List<List<String>> makePerms(List<String> list, int count) {
    if (count == 1) {
      return list.stream().map(Arrays::asList).collect(toList());
    }
    return list.stream()
          .flatMap(e -> makePerms(remove(list, e), count - 1).stream()
                .map(l -> add(l, e)))
          .collect(toList());
  }

  private static <T> List<T> remove(List<T> list, T elem) {
    List<T> newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
    newList.remove(elem);
    return newList;
  }

  private static <T> List<T> add(List<T> list, T elem) {
    List<T> newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
    newList.add(elem);
    return newList;
  }

  private static void printPerm(List<String> perm) {
    perm.forEach(System.out::print);
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your swap. Your swap is not swapping the elements in the array. As it is getting two strings and swapping them but it is not changing the value inside the array. Fix your swap and it will be fine.

Comment: It's hard to read the code in the format you have posted but I am glad the answer helped. you should click "accept" on the right answer.

Comment: I've updated the code and question. Any tips on how to get the code to only print out the first 4 arrangements? Because that is where I'm still stuck at.

Answer (score 0):

mine is pretty similar to Donat. take an element and return len-1 permutations of the rest of the elements.

```
public class Permuter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> source = asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
    List<String> permutations = returnPermutations(source, 3, 0);
    permutations.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
}

private static List<String> returnPermutations(List<String> source, int choose, int len) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    if (len + 1 == choose) {
        return source;
    } else {
        for (String s : source) {
            List<String> tail = new ArrayList<>(source);
            tail.remove(s);
            result.addAll(returnPermutations(tail, choose, len+1).stream().map(ts -> s + ts)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
        return result;
    }
}

}
```